How can I remove a prefixing or suffixing date,or datetime, from a string in powershell
As part of a bigger powershell task, I need to remove a date (or datetime) prefix or suffix from a string (Actually a filename) The filename is returned from a file watcher, where the filter is *.txt. The file will either have a preceding YYYYMMDD or a suffixing YYYYMMDDHHNN which needs to be removed.
As an example the filename returned could be "D:\TESTLDB\DirIn\CRIS_Invoice_202411140311.txt" I require the CRIS_Invoice_ part. Alternatively It could be D:\TESTBCH\d\l\var\ra\ifc,20241114.Rentbals.txt
$File = "D:\TESTLB\DirIn\CRIS_Invoice_202411140311.txt"

$Path = Split-Path -Path $File -Parent
$FileName = Split-Path -Path $File -Leaf
$FileName = ( $FileName.Replace( '_\d{12}.' , '_*.' ) )

Expecting Filename to Be CRIS_Invoice_*.txt
Well that was odd ...
`$FileName = $FileName.Replace( '_\d{12}.' , '_*.' ).Replace('\d{8}.' , '*.')`

Does not work, but
    $FileName = $FileName -Replace ( '_\d{12}.' , '_*.') -Replace('\d{8}.' , '*.')
Works as expected in that CRIS_Invoice_202411140311.txt is returned as CRIS_Invoice*.txt and 20241114.RentBals.txt" becomes *.RentBals.txt. OSBalances.txt isn't touched. So I sort of have an answer, but would love to know why the .Replace() method does not work and the -Replace operator does.
I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it if anyone wants to obfuscate the code :D

.Replace is a method on the System.String class and is used for literal replacements, doesn't know what regex is whereas -replace is a PowerShell operator that directs the call to Regex.Replace static method using IgnoreCase as default its default RegexOptions. That's why.
